# DFH: Sizeof(Object) giving weird output with fin.seekg();

Tags: file-handling, turbo-c++

Here is the function:

```
void debugged_read()
{
    clrscr();
    stu S1;
    ifstream fin;
    eof=false;

    fin.open("CP2.dat", ios::binary);   //Opens the file again
    while(fin.eof() == false) {
        cout<<"\n\n Initial location: "<<fin.tellg();
        fin.read((char*)& S1, sizeof(S1)); //Reads a Record into fin stream
        S1.show();
        cout<<"\n\n After Read location: "<<fin.tellg();


        fin.read((char*)& S1, sizeof(S1)); //Reads the next record space for eof detection
        cout<<"\n Check position: "<<fin.tellg();
        if(fin.eof() == true) {
            cprintf("\nWARNING: End of file Incoming!");
            break;  //Break on eof encounter
        }
        else {
            fin.seekg(-(sizeof(S1)), ios :: cur);  //File Pointer Correction
            cout<<"\n File Pointer Corrected: "<<fin.tellg();
        }
    }
cout<<"\nRead Successful!";
fin.close();
}
```

This function returned an expected output if I used a **long** variable to store the size of the object S1 of 'stu' class.
[image]

but using the sizeof(); directly it gives this weird output:
[image]

Comment: Don't use screen shots of text. Just copy and paste the text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof` returns [size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) which is `unsigned int`

`istream::read` expects [streamsize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize) which is `signed int`

Comment: Okay, I see how that explains that random number. But why did it still read the file normally? I was expecting some garbage values

Comment: @AlphaMineron because `istream::read`, as the majority of the standard functions, is pretty well-secured and it doesn't read that doesn't exist but sets some warning flags, which you can (and should) check. Just make yourself a good habit to look into the reference documentation :)

Comment: Okay, I'll start doing that. Although, is it normal that I don't understand the documentation? For example, the cppreference.com links that you linked in your answer, I wasn't able to fully understand everything on the page. I believe this just the beginners' struggle, right?

Comment: @AlphaMineron yeah, that's totally fine, `cppreference` is quite formal and has _all_ (i think) the information about every little thing. For learning, I would definitely recommend reading this website end-to-end : http://www.learncpp.com/